# Dynamic fields from Schema

Tags: 2013, schema

Can i create a schema from GUI, such a way

Eg : Schema A has

1. Color field (dropdown) having values Red and Yellow.

When I select green, set of fields should display,

When i select red, set of other fields should display.

Is this possible in 2013 Tridon?

Comment: The closest the GUI has is the tree view selection against a Category with nested Keywords. Put select Keywords under the Green field and different Keywords under Red. You can't re-use keywords in this way though (e.g. Yellow can't appear twice).

Comment: One question, though -- would you prefer this type of dynamic relationship specific to the Schema or could it be something related to a Category as properties of its keywords?

Answer (score 6):

The only way to build such a Schema would be with a GUI Extension and complex metadata against each field.

It would be much easier to have a "Green Schema", "Red Schema" etc... and a shared Embedded Schema to hold common fields between them.

This also give you more use of SDL Tridion features, like where used, limiting Component Templates, Easier Template logic etc...